# Substraction of rows ( A1-A2, A3-A4 etc. )

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I was wondering if there is a simple way to subtract form odd rows even rows. Basically: first row (A1) minus second row (A2), third row (A3) minus fourth row (A4).

```
test <- structure(list(Well_positions = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", 
"A6", "A7", "A8", "A9", "A10", "A11", "A12"), Layout = c("SM1_1", 
"BA1", "SM1_2", "BB1", "SM1_3", "BC1", "SM1_4", "BD1", "SM1_5", 
"BE1", "ST1_1", "BF1"), Abs_18 = c(0.20585, 0.16226, 0.1695, 
0.11268, 0.16271, 0.11269, 0.23633, 0.18636, 0.22289, 0.18856, 
0.11974, 0.059685), FL_18 = c(3669, 51, 3578, 52, 3594, 51, 5378, 
55, 5104, 54, 825, 58)), .Names = c("Well_positions", "Layout", 
"Abs_18", "FL_18"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

So far I had only an idea to create two seperate dataframes:

```
library(dplyr)

data_s <- filter(test, grepl("S", Layout))
data_b <-filter(test, grepl("B", Layout))
```

And then I would like to keep "Well_positions" and "Layout" from `data_s` and get the difference of the rest of the columns (`data_s[,3:4] - data_b[,3:4]`). But there I have no idea how to keep two first columns... What I could do is add two columns form data_b and then perform the subtraction but when I have more columns it gets really messy.

Comment: you have an odd number of rows in your example, can it be the case in your data and if so how would you handle it ?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, i have even number of rows. There is more data, I just cut it wrong way.. Should be fine now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
test2 <- test %>%
  group_by(grp = (row_number() - 1) %/% 2) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(ifelse(is.numeric(.), first(.) - last(.), first(.)))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-grp)
test2
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  Well_positions Layout   Abs_18 FL_18
           <chr>  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
1             A1  SM1_1 0.043590  3618
2             A3  SM1_2 0.056820  3526
3             A5  SM1_3 0.050020  3543
4             A7  SM1_4 0.049970  5323
5             A9  SM1_5 0.034330  5050
6            A11  ST1_1 0.060055   767
```

Comment: @magruc I am happy you pick this one :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
    result <- test[c(TRUE, FALSE),]

    result$Abs_18 <- result$Abs_18 - test$Abs_18[c(FALSE,TRUE)]
    result$FL_18 <- result$FL_18 - test$FL_18[c(FALSE,TRUE)]
```

This saves every odd row (1, 3, 5, etc.) into a new dataframe so you can keept the layout and well positions. Then you just substract the values from the even rows of column 3 and 4 of the `test`-data frame from your new dataframe.

Answer (score 3):

Building on @brettljausn's filtering solution:

```
library(dplyr)
test %>% {cbind(.[c(T,F),] %>% rename_all(paste0,"_1"),
                .[c(F,T),] %>% rename_all(paste0,"_2"))} %>%
  mutate(delta_Abs_18 = Abs_18_1 - Abs_18_2,
         delta_FL_18  = FL_18_1  - FL_18_2)

#   Well_positions_1 Layout_1 Abs_18_1 FL_18_1 Well_positions_2 Layout_2 Abs_18_2 FL_18_2 delta_Abs_18 delta_FL_18
# 1               A1    SM1_1  0.20585    3669               A2      BA1 0.162260      51     0.043590        3618
# 2               A3    SM1_2  0.16950    3578               A4      BB1 0.112680      52     0.056820        3526
# 3               A5    SM1_3  0.16271    3594               A6      BC1 0.112690      51     0.050020        3543
# 4               A7    SM1_4  0.23633    5378               A8      BD1 0.186360      55     0.049970        5323
# 5               A9    SM1_5  0.22289    5104              A10      BE1 0.188560      54     0.034330        5050
# 6              A11    ST1_1  0.11974     825              A12      BF1 0.059685      58     0.060055         767
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
test %>%
  mutate_all(funs(lead(.))) %>%
  bind_cols(test, .) %>%
  filter(rep(1:2, length.out = n()) == 1) %>%
  mutate(diff_Abs = Abs_18 - Abs_181,
         diff_FL = FL_18 - FL_181)
```

**Result:**

```
  Well_positions Layout  Abs_18 FL_18 Well_positions1 Layout1  Abs_181 FL_181 diff_Abs
1             A1  SM1_1 0.20585  3669              A2     BA1 0.162260     51 0.043590
2             A3  SM1_2 0.16950  3578              A4     BB1 0.112680     52 0.056820
3             A5  SM1_3 0.16271  3594              A6     BC1 0.112690     51 0.050020
4             A7  SM1_4 0.23633  5378              A8     BD1 0.186360     55 0.049970
5             A9  SM1_5 0.22289  5104             A10     BE1 0.188560     54 0.034330
6            A11  ST1_1 0.11974   825             A12     BF1 0.059685     58 0.060055
  diff_FL
1    3618
2    3526
3    3543
4    5323
5    5050
6     767
```

Only keep desired columns:

```
test %>%
  mutate_all(funs(lead(.))) %>%
  bind_cols(test, .) %>%
  filter(rep(1:2, length.out = n()) == 1) %>%
  mutate(diff_Abs = Abs_18 - Abs_181,
         diff_FL = FL_18 - FL_181) %>%
  select(Well_positions, Layout, starts_with("diff"))
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  Well_positions Layout diff_Abs diff_FL
           <chr>  <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl>
1             A1  SM1_1 0.043590    3618
2             A3  SM1_2 0.056820    3526
3             A5  SM1_3 0.050020    3543
4             A7  SM1_4 0.049970    5323
5             A9  SM1_5 0.034330    5050
6            A11  ST1_1 0.060055     767
```

Answer (score 2):

This consider both odd and even row condition :)

```
if (dim(test)[1]%%2!=0){
group=c(rep(1:((dim(test)[1]-1)/2), each=2),(dim(test)[1]-1)/2+1)}else{
group=rep(1:((dim(test)[1])/2), each=2)
  }

test$group=group
t1=test%>%group_by(group)%>%dplyr::summarise(Abs18=ifelse(n()==1,`Abs 18`,diff(`Abs 18`)),FL18=ifelse(n()==1,`FL 18`,diff(`FL 18`)))


t2=test%>%group_by(group)%>%dplyr::slice(1)

t2[,c('Abs 18','FL 18')]=abs(t1[,2:3])

t2
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   group [6]
  `Well positions` Layout `Abs 18` `FL 18` group
             <chr>  <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
1               A1  SM1_1  0.04359    3618     1
2               A3  SM1_2  0.05682    3526     2
3               A5  SM1_3  0.05002    3543     3
4               A7  SM1_4  0.04997    5323     4
5               A9  SM1_5  0.03433    5050     5
6              A11  ST1_1  0.11974     825     6
```